# Return wrong getUrl

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

i need print this url:

`http://mysite.com/hello-world-product.html`

i use this:

`echo $this->getUrl('hello-world-product.html')`

and that return this (see the last character wrong):

`http://mysite.com/hello-world-product.html/`

What can i do for return right value?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`getUrl` parameters](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/reference/geturl_function_parameters) for details.

```
echo $this->getUrl('', array('_direct' => 'hello-world-product.html'));
```

However if this product is an actual product then it's more resilient to use:

```
echo $this->getUrl('catalog/product/view', array('id' => ID_OF_PRODUCT, '_use_rewrite' => true));
```

Comment: Adds the trailing slash, how can you redirect without the slash being added?

Comment: @VaishalPatel The first method (the one with `_direct`) should not have a trailing slash.